# /tf suddenly missing

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, robot-description, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using a robot run with Raspberry Pi 3, and I'm controlling it from my computer using ROS_MASTER_URI. As usual, after loading my robot_description parameter and  run robot_state_publisher node, I can view my robot in Rviz from /tf, but suddenly, when I re-run the process, Rviz said "no tf data", although the topic /tf still exist and there still have the robot_description parameter. What could be the problem? I have struggled with this for days.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398048//tf-suddenly-missing/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2022-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-03-27**:
Did you restart the ros-master (roscore)? All ros nodes must be restarted if the ros-master restarts, including rviz.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2022-03-27**:
Thanks Mike for your reply, good to see you. I figured out the problem and will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a while, I found the solution. When I echo the /tf topic in my computer's terminal, nothing is displayed, but when I did that in the Pi3's terminal, those data appeared. Then I think it may be the connection problem. I realized that there were many devices using the Wifi, so I turn off some of them and restart the machine, then everything back to normal.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) with karma: 58 on 2022-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0